# How to attach for example a #top reference to a <p:commandLink>?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I just wondered how I can attach a reference like a #top to the target action of a commandLink?

Basically in my situation this `<p:commandLink>` sits in a `<p:dataTable>` and sets the row-value to the `current`-Property of a bean:

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false"
               action="#{bean.viewSomePage()}"
               value="#{record.name}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{record}"
                                     target="#{bean.current}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

In the bean the `viewSomePage()`-Method just delivers the navigation target:

```
public String viewSomePage() {
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The address bar of the browser shows then `index.xhtml`. But how can I achieve that something like `index.xhtml#status`is shown?

What I want to do is to link on a specific `<p:tab>` of a `<p:tabView>`according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222689/how-can-i-make-primefaces-tabs-linkable/14222690#14222690). It is already working, but I am not able to link it through a `<p:commandLink>`. Of course I already tried to simply attach it in the `viewSomePage()`-Method, with no success.

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by JSF navigation handler. Your best bet is manually invoking [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) with the desired URL with the desired fragment identifier:

```
public void viewSomePage() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/index.xhtml#status");
}
```

Or if you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) already:

```
public void viewSomePage() throws IOException {
    Faces.redirect("index.xhtml#status");
}
```